# PostMessage WM_LBUTTONDOWN issues with position

Tags: c++, input, postmessage, vnc

Hello and thank to read me.

Since some weeks, i'm working on a "VNC". The features are very basic. A user (U1) runs a program that displays a password. The second user (U2) enters the IP of (U1) user and the password.

My code is functional (not without some bug for the moment), it correctly displays the screen and correctly sends the information (click, mouse moovement, ect ..).

There is only "one" problem. The position send to the (U1) is corect but when it call PostMessageA, the position of the mouse after the call is wrong. I only use WINAPI.

I use the following API to get Screen size : GetSystemMetrics()

Then do the following :

```
InputStruct.lParam = MAKELPARAM(point.x, point.y);      
PostMessageA(hWnd, InputStruct.msg, InputStruct.wParam, InputStruct.lParam);
```

If someone has already worked on this bug, I would be really happy to have more information. I do not usually ask questions and just read questions already, but this time I'm really in the dark.

Thank a lot for your time,
Ely.

EDIT 1 :

Thank for your intention, i'm getting the point like this :
The (U2) send the msg to (U1) using sock, then i parse it and get the "lParam"

```
point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(InputStruct.lParam);
point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(InputStruct.lParam);
```

Then i get the hwnd from this point

```
hWnd = WindowFromPoint(point);
```

Then converting it

```
ScreenToClient(currHwnd, &point);
```

And finaly call PostMessage

```
InputStruct.lParam = MAKELPARAM(point.x, point.y);      

PostMessageA(hWnd, InputStruct.msg, InputStruct.wParam, InputStruct.lParam);
```

Comment: The `lParam` of `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` carries coordinates that are relative to the target window's client area, not the screen. Are you accounting for that when calculating the `point`? And why are you posting `WM_BUTTONDOWN` messages at all? You should be using `SendInput()` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau i'm editing

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank for your intention, i have edited my question with more details. Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think the "calculating of the point" is good with "ScreenToClient()". Unfortunatly, i can't use SendInput() in my work.. I have tested with this api and it works pretty fine (only 4-5 pixel miss positioning instead of ~50).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hello, i have still not resolve this problem, but i'm using SetProcessDPIAware. Can it be the origin of the problem ?